# Proof that for any real number $x$, $-|x| \leq x \leq |x|$. Is my proof too good to be true?

Tags: proof-verification

This comes from one of the exercises in *How to Prove It* by Daniel Velleman. In this proof I invoke the theorem from the previous exercise: “for all real numbers $a$ and $b$, $|a| \leq b$ iff $-b \leq a \leq b$.” I won’t include that proof here, as I am virtually certain it is valid. Anyway, here is my proof:

---

**Theorem.** For any real number $x$, $-|x| \leq x \leq |x|$.

*Proof.* Let $x$ be an arbitrary real number. We can of course write $x = x$, as this is a tautology. By taking the absolute value of both sides of this equation, it follows that $|x| = |x|$. Given this, by the theorem in the previous problem we can conclude that $-|x| \leq x \leq |x|$. Since $x$ was arbitrary, this is true for all real numbers $x$.

---

I apologize if this seems basic, but I’m really doubting this proof, and I couldn’t find anything similar in my searches.

Comment: What is invalid? If the previous exercise is true, let $a=x$ and $b=|x|$, and then $|x|\le|x|$ if and only if $-|x|\le x \le |x|$. (It would help in your proof to say what you are letting $a$ and $b$ equal in your use of the previous exercise.)

Comment: @JavaMan Did you mean to say the proof is valid?

Comment: Your proof is valid. However it would improve readability by a great deal if you explicitly wrote down the choices of $a$ and $b$. Now it's up to the reader to see or indeed not see your intention.

Comment: @maxmilgram I'm still getting the hang of which details to include and which to leave out. But now that you point it out I see that you're absolutely correct. I should have specified my choices for $a$ and $b$. Thanks for the feedback.